# Error while opening places.sqlite database firefox

Tags: python, sqlite

I get this error :

`sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database`

while executing this code :

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('d:\Users\Vladi\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\iz2stysq.default\places.sqlite')
cur = con.cursor()
data = cur.execute("SELECT input FROM moz_inputhistory")
```

Yes the path is correct, so... What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?  Because `\U` denotes a Unicode character in a Python string literal.

Comment: Try `r"d:\Users\Vladi\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\iz2stysq.default\places.sqlite"` instead

Comment: try this: `print 'hey\new comer'`  and `print r'hey\new comer'`, using the \ on windows, you have to add `r` for `raw` so it dont interprets the special chars like `\n \t ...etc`

Comment: `>>> con = sqlite3.connect(r'd:\Users\Vladi\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\iz2stysq.default\places.sqlite')


>>> cur = con.cursor()


>>> data = cur.execute("SELECT input FROM moz_inputhistory")


Traceback (most recent call last):


  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>


sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database`

Comment: So I still not see :<

Comment: @Maxim Did you create your DB using python code?

Comment: No it's the database from Mozilla Firefox

Comment: `\ ` is special is Python litteral strings, you should always double it (or use `r` prefix as kartikg3 said) : `con = sqlite3.connect('d:\\Users\\Vladi\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\iz2stysq.default\places.sqlite')` ... but still unsure

Comment: Please consider changing "places.sqlite" to ".sqlite" in the title. This problem affects every sqlite db. Not only places.sqlite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all versions of `sqlite` and `pysqlite` seem to be compatible with firefox's sqlite format.

Check your `sqlite` and `pysqlite` versions and environment with

```
import sys, sqlite3

print sys.version
print sqlite3.version
print sqlite3.sqlite_version
```

I've checked the same file `places.sqlite` in four different environments and got **different errors** on two of them (cygwin and canopy). On `debian` and with `sqlite-shell-win32-x86-3080801` it works as expected. See my summary below.

on **canopy** fails

```
  sys.version -> 2.7.6 | 64-bit | (default, Jun  4 2014, 16:30:34) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
  sqlite3.version -> 2.6.0
  sqlite3.sqlite_version -> 3.6.21
  ERROR -> DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

on **cygwin on Windows 7** fails

```
  sys.version -> 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2012, 13:50:09) [GCC 4.5.3]
  sqlite3.version -> 2.6.0
  sqlite3.sqlite_version -> 3.7.17
  ERROR -> sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

on **debian** it works!

```
  sys.version -> 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40) [GCC 4.4.5]
  sqlite3.version -> 2.4.1
  sqlite3.sqlite_version -> 3.7.3
  it works!
```

on **sqlite-shell-win32-x86-3080801 [Windows 7 (MS-DOS-Box)]** it works!

```
  sqlite3.exe -version -> 3.8.8.1 2015-01-20 16:51:25 f73337e3e289915a76ca96e7a05a1a8d4e890d55
  it works!
```